# JAXB set @XmlRootElement

Tags: xml, jaxb

is it possible to set the @XmlRootElement in runtime?
i have a class that i need to convert to xml, but this class should be converted to more than one XML and the only different is the root element name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the class represents an XML schema type that can be used by more than one element name then it should not be annotated `@XmlRootElement`.  Instead it should be annotated `@XmlType`, and when you want to marshal an instance of `MyType` to XML you wrap it in a `JAXBElement<MyType>` that specifies the element name.

Comment: +1 - FYI - JAXB (JSR-222) doesn't require any annotations on a class.  You only need to use an `@XmlType` annotation if you want to specify configuration on it (i.e. type name, factory class, etc):  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan true, I'm too used to working schema first where everything is fully annotated.

Comment: @IanRoberts What if we use a jaxb2Marshaller where a XmlRootElement is mandatory :(?